# Android numberPicker passing android widget as value

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I have a calculator that so far is using a text view for me to type the inputs, but in order to avoid any errors or mistypes I want to change these to number pickers. So, I have been trying different ways and this is what I have. It is nearly working, but I don't know how to do the next step. One of the fields is time, so I need a format like mm:ss or hh:mm:ss, thing is i can't use doubles or anything like that on numberPickers so I tried this.

[Layout](https://imgur.com/a/RuC8W)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Code:

```
  pickerMinutes.minValue = 0
    pickerMinutes.maxValue = 60
    pickerMinutes.wrapSelectorWheel = false
    pickerMinutes.isEnabled = true

    pickerSeconds.minValue = 0
    pickerSeconds.maxValue = 60
    pickerSeconds.wrapSelectorWheel = false
    pickerSeconds.isEnabled = true


    pickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
       time.text = newVal.toString() + ":"
    }
    pickerSeconds.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
        time.text = newVal.toString() + pickerMinutes
    }
```

**EDIT**

I did this and it kind of works, but it uses the same value.
Do you know how I can modify it?

```
pickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
       time.text = newVal.toString() + ":" + newVal
}
```

[Picture](https://imgur.com/a/xRZlJ)

Comment: You have concat  "pickerMinutes" which is picker number object on time.text = newVal.toString() + pickerMinutes

Comment: yes I know.. that was my attempt to make it work, because like I said I need the correct format. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you check my edit

Comment: time.text = pickerMinutes.getValue() + ":" + newVal in pickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener

Comment: I tried that before, but I got an error on the + sign: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Comment: Try to sent in pickerSeconds.setOnValueChangedListener like time.text = pickerMinutes.getValue() + ":" + newVal

Comment: same... they are the same, just with different name

Comment: Anyone with any ideas?